# Bestw.d format syntax in SAS

Tags: format, sas

I am converting a character variable to a numeric variable.  I am using a `bestw.d` format.  I also tried just `best.` as the format in the input statement and this worked fine.  I cant find any mention of just using `best.` instead of `bestw.` in SAS help, though I know from SAS help that the `d` can be omitted.  I have been playing around with using just the `best.`and I am wondering if there is a default `w` assigned when just using `best.`.

Comment: Note it is `bestw.` not `bestw.d`, as you cannot specify decimals (as `best` is doing that work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All formats have a default w.  It is not generally good practice to use `best.` (or `<format>.`) in most cases, as you should know and plan for the specific width needed, but it always exists.

Also, informat and format have different defaults in many cases where there are identically named informat and format.

In the case of `bestw.`, the default length is 12.  See [this documentation page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000184495.htm) for details.

Answer (score 3):

I always find it's worth using a worked example, this shows the different outcomes when using lengths on the `BEST.` format:

```
data _NULL_;
a=1031564321300.302;
  put '==================================';
  put 'Different "BEST" formats';
  put '==================================';
  put 'BEST8. - ' a best8.;
  put 'BEST12. - ' a best12.;
  put 'BEST13. - ' a best13.;
  put '==================================';
  put 'BEST. - ' a best.;
  put '==================================';
run;
```

You can run this in your environment and check the outcome. On my machine it looks like this:

```
==================================
Different "BEST" formats
==================================
BEST8. - 1.032E12
BEST12. - 1.0315643E12
BEST13. - 1031564321300
==================================
BEST. - 1.0315643E12
==================================
```

i.e. It looks like `BEST12.` is the matching format when no width is specified.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the response.